# Ant move puts newline at the end of property

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have an Ant task in Eclipse to get version from file:

```
<loadfile property="version" srcfile="version.txt">
  <filterchain>
    <linecontainsregexp>
      <regexp pattern="^#define version .(\d{1,10})\.(\d{1,10})\.(\d{1,10})\.(\d{1,10})."/>
    </linecontainsregexp>
    <replaceregex 
         pattern="^#define version .(\d{1,10})\.(\d{1,10})\.(\d{1,10})\.(\d{1,10})..*$" 
         replace="\1.\2.\3.\4" />
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>  
<echo message="Version ${version}"/>
```

The version displays without a newline. Further in the code I want to use the property with the move task:

```
<move file="${dir}\file.exe"
      tofile="${outputdir}\output-${version}-xxx.exe" 
      overwrite="true" 
      force="true" />
```

But it fails with the message

```
BUILD FAILED build.xml:26: Failed to copy path\file.exe to path\output_directory\output-1.0.0.0
-xxx.exe due to output-1.0.0.0
-xxx.exe (Název souboru či adresáře nebo jmenovka svazku je nesprávná)
```

(the last line means that the file name is invalid, obviously it contains newline in the middle).

Where am I going wrong? Is it the property itself? Even adding the line

```
<replaceregex pattern="&#10;" replace="" flags="s"/>
```

or other attempts to remove newlines from the property did not change anything.

Comment: Your two filter readers appear to be incompatible. `<linecontainsregexp>` matches on `#define version`, but `<replaceregex>` works on `#define jawscompleteversion`. A line from version.txt containing `#define jawscompleteversion` won't make it past the `<linecontainsregexp>`.

Comment: I am sorry, I wanted to shorten the property names and forgot one. Actually it is jawscompleteversion but I shortened it to version everywhere. I edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [strip line breaks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#striplinebreaks), e.g.:

```
<filterchain>
  <linecontainsregexp ... />
  <replaceregex ... />

  <striplinebreaks />

</filterchain>
```

If you modify your `<echo>` to:

```
<echo message="Version -${version}-"/>
```

you'll see the affect clearly.

Comment: Thanks, this one worked. I dont know why my other attempts (removing the newline characters with a regexp) did not. I even doubted it to be the property since Eclipse output it without a newline, I should have thought to put characters at the end of the output.